# In kotlin how to use ViewModel With ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

In my current project I use the next line:

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

For instance a `ViewModel` but in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html#ViewModelProviders() recommend use `ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory` because `ViewModelProviders()` was deprecated in API level 1.1.0.

any idea for this purpose?

Comment: Can you share piece of code that you're using to create `ViewModel` instance?

Comment: mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

Answer (score 9):

If you had a simple ViewModel extending AndroidViewModel **without any** additional constructor parameters, its as follows

> 1. Extend AndroidViewModel without any additional constructor
>      parameters

```
class FooViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {}
```

> 2. Create View Model in Activity

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FooViewModel::class.java)
```

---

But if you had a ViewModel extending AndroidViewModel **with any** additional constructor parameters, its as follows

> 1. Extend AndroidViewModel with any additional constructor
>      parameters

```
class FooViewModel(application: Application, foo: Foo) : AndroidViewModel(application) {}
```

> 2. Create a new view model factory extending ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory

```
class FooViewModelFactory(val application: Application, val foo: Foo): ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application) {

            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return FooViewModel(
                    application, foo
                ) as T
            }

     }
```

> 3. Create View Model in Activity

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, FooViewModelFactory(application, foo)).get(FooViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: The original question is now irrelevant, as you should no longer use the `ViewModelProviders` utility class. Instead, you should create a `ViewModelProvider` instance like so:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(thisFragment).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Original answer below.

---

`ViewModelProviders` is just a utility class with static methods, there's no need to instantiate it (there are no instance methods in it anyway), so the constructor being deprecated shouldn't be a concern.

The way you use it is by calling its appropriate `of` method for your use case, passing in a `Fragment` or `Activity`, and then calling `get` on the `ViewModelProvider` it returns:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(thisFragment).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

If you don't provide your own factory in the second parameter of the `of` method, `AndroidViewModelFactory` will be used by default. This implementation can either create ViewModel subclasses that have no constructor parameters, or ones that extend `AndroidViewModel`, like such:

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    // use application

}
```

Comment: yeah i use this code but how to use ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This class is deprecated, use `ViewModelProvider` (without the s)

Answer (score 3):

you can try this code

```
    ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application).create(UserViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use AndroidViewModelFactory like this:

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application))
            .get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, it is quite simple:

```
// This is the deprecated way to create a viewModel.
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(owner).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

//This is the deprecated way to create a viewModel with a factory.
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(owner, mViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

---

```
// This is the new way to create a viewModel.
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(owner).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

//This is the new way to create a viewModel with a factory.
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(owner, mViewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open build.gradle(Module:~.app)
2. Edit appcompat version to 1.3.0-alpha02

   ```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
   ```

Comment: My  another answer using AndroidViewModelFactory is better than this, I think.