# How to fix 'Cannot create an instance of class....'?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my **build.gradle**

dependencies {

```
//viewmodel
def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1'
```

}

**viewModel**

class AlarmViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

```
private var repository : AlarmRepository = AlarmRepository(application)
var list : LiveData<List<Alarm>> = repository.list
```

}

**Fragment**

class AlarmListFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var viewModel: AlarmViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentAlarmListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity!!.application)).get(AlarmViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

}

Searching on google and trying to fix but it doesn't work
plz help me :<
I need ur helpe!!!

Comment: There is similar code to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489933/in-kotlin-how-to-use-viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-androidviewmodelfactory. Also, please, set breakpoints inside `AlarmViewModel` and debug to make sure it doesn't throw exception.

Comment: thank u  but same not working T_T........

Comment: can you post your errors?

Comment: error message is    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.jisoo.alarmtutorialproject.viewmodel.AlarmViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:236)
        at com.jisoo.alarmtutorialproject.AlarmListFragment.onViewCreated(AlarmListFragment.kt:40)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3019)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:551)
        at ........................

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.jisoo.alarmtutorialproject.viewmodel.AlarmViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:236)

Comment: The same error occurs when I import any code written in the answer.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523837/cannot-create-an-instance-of-class-viewmodel-class

Comment: As pointed by @sasikumar in the shared answer, you need to create a view model Factory to provide application instance to your view model

Comment: Shouldn't I use androidviewmodelfactory instead of custom factory?